# `java.io.EOFException: null` when listing topics in Kafka

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I am simply trying to use the `listTopics()` method of the AdminClient class with `kafka-clients` 2.7.0 Java API. I am running kafka and zookeeper as docker containers and have the following docker-compose configuration:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  zookeeper:
    image: zookeeper
    container_name: zookeeper
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
    environment:
      - ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT=2181

  kafka:
    image: debezium/kafka
    container_name: kafka
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
    environment:
    - KAFKA_HEAP_OPTS=-Xmx512M -Xms512M
    - ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=zookeeper:2181
    - KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME=kafka
    - KAFKA_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:9092,PLAINTEXT://kafka:29092
    - KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:9092,PLAINTEXT://kafka:29092
    - KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP=PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT
    - KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME=PLAINTEXT
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
```

Moreover, I am creating an AdminClient:

```
public MyAdminClient() {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        String bootstrapServers = "localhost:9092";
        props.setProperty(AdminClientConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers);
        props.setProperty(AdminClientConfig.DEFAULT_API_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG, "540000");
        myAdmin = AdminClient.create(props);
    }
```

I am attempting to list the topics with the created myAdmin object:

```
        ListTopicsOptions options = new ListTopicsOptions();
        options.listInternal(true);
        KafkaFuture<Set<String>> topicsFuture = streamAdmin.listTopics(options).names();
        Set<String> topics = topicsFuture.get();
        
        for (String topic: topics) {
            System.out.println("[Kafka topic]: "+topic);
        }
```

However, I am getting getting an `java.io.EOFException: null` is being thrown in a loop:

```
18:19:17.404 [main] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.KafkaAdminClient - [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Queueing Call(callName=listTopics, deadlineMs=1618504097402, tries=0, nextAllowedTryMs=0) with a timeout 540000 ms from now.
18:19:17.418 [kafka-admin-client-thread | adminclient-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Initiating connection to node localhost:9092 (id: -1 rack: null) using address localhost/127.0.0.1
18:19:17.447 [kafka-admin-client-thread | adminclient-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector - [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Created socket with SO_RCVBUF = 342972, SO_SNDBUF = 146988, SO_TIMEOUT = 0 to node -1
18:19:17.961 [kafka-admin-client-thread | adminclient-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Completed connection to node -1. Fetching API versions.
18:19:17.962 [kafka-admin-client-thread | adminclient-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Initiating API versions fetch from node -1.
18:19:17.998 [kafka-admin-client-thread | adminclient-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Sending API_VERSIONS request with header RequestHeader(apiKey=API_VERSIONS, apiVersion=3, clientId=adminclient-1, correlationId=0) and timeout 3600000 to node -1: {client_software_name=apache-kafka-java,client_software_version=2.7.0,_tagged_fields={}}
18:19:18.024 [kafka-admin-client-thread | adminclient-1] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector - [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Connection with localhost/127.0.0.1 disconnected
java.io.EOFException: null
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.NetworkReceive.readFrom(NetworkReceive.java:97)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.receive(KafkaChannel.java:447)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.read(KafkaChannel.java:397)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.attemptRead(Selector.java:674)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.pollSelectionKeys(Selector.java:576)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.poll(Selector.java:481)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.poll(NetworkClient.java:561)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.KafkaAdminClient$AdminClientRunnable.processRequests(KafkaAdminClient.java:1329)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.KafkaAdminClient$AdminClientRunnable.run(KafkaAdminClient.java:1260)
```

Comment: Can you check if the broker version is >= 0.10.0.0?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this issue by enforcing the KAFKA_LISTENERS to point to the kafka broker host `kafka` as opposed to localhost.

- KAFKA_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT_HOST://kafka:9092,PLAINTEXT://kafka:29092

Comment: You shouldn't use the container name for the listeners, only the advertised ones. Just use 0.0.0.0

Comment: why not? this seems to be working for the confluent community:
https://gist.github.com/rmoff/da2e882a49a55740b242df893e48734f#file-docker-compose-yml

Comment: By using a hostname, you're limiting traffic to only that name, not external to the container (assuming you actually want to use the port mapping to the host)